# WCF ServiceHost Close() itself

Tags: wcf, servicehost

I have an application which offers a "Stop()" OperationContract.
When it is called the application should close() the ServiceHost.

```
public void Stop()
{
    try
    {
        _serviceHost.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
    catch (CommunicationException comEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(comEx.ToString());
        _serviceHost.Abort();
    }
}
```

Of course this is a problem because the incoming request is still active when trying to close the ServiceHost. How do I circumvent that issue? Separate thread on a short delay?

```
public void Stop()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(WaitAndKill);
}


private void WaitAndKill()
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    _managementServiceHost.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is your service session based?

Comment: You can either wait (start a timer for example) and then close the host or you can implement a host controller - another WCF service, that will be always running and will be responsible for launching and closing your _managementServiceHost (for example using new Process)